# Exponential Regression: Translate mathematical notation to Excel syntax

Tags: excel, math, syntax, excel-formula, notation

I have a question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site where I ask about generating an [exponential regression equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895760/basic-exponential-regression-equation/2895836#2895836).

One of the [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2895836/389017) provides a **mathematical solution** to my problem. The solution is written in **mathematical notation**:

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not a math wiz, and I'm having trouble translating the mathematical notation to Microsoft Excel syntax.

**What would the math look like in Excel?**

```
    +--------------+---------------+
    |    X (AGE)   | Y (CONDITION) |
    +--------------+---------------+
    |       0      |       20      |
    |       1      |       20      |
    |       2      |       20      |
    |       3      |       20      |
    |       4      |       20      |
    |       5      |       20      |
    |       6      |       18      |
    |       7      |       18      |
    |       8      |       18      |
    |       9      |       18      |
    |       10     |       16      |
    |       11     |       16      |
    |       12     |       14      |
    |       13     |       14      |
    |       14     |       12      |
    |       15     |       12      |
    |       16     |       10      |
    |       17     |        8      |
    |       18     |        6      |
    |       19     |        4      |
    |       20     |        2      |
    +--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi Wilson, this question is not quite on topic for Stack Overflow. We could help with it if you could first give us the mathematical notation in plain English, and then we could help you translate that into an Excel formula. Maybe you could ask for the formula to be explained in more detail on [math.se] Stack Exchange and then come here for us to help you work on it in Excel. Here is what's on topic on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: My (limited) understanding of the math answer is that the formula for a above is just another way of getting to an estimate of a that you get by taking logs (.147). It's only an estimate because taking logs mashes up the error structure a bit. If you want to get an estimate closer to the one that you would get by doing a non-linear regression (.149),  @Claude Leibovici is advising you to use the formulas for f(a) and f'(a) further down so I think those and the recurrence relation for a(n+1)=a(n)-f(a(n))/f'(a(n)) should be in your question.

Comment: Is this wildly different from doing exponential trend with =RSQ(LN(y),x) ? Where c: =EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN(y),x),1,2)) and b: =INDEX(LINEST(LN(y),x),1) in the form  y = c *e ^(b * x)  ?

Comment: Not wildly different - if you put =INDEX(LINEST(LN(21-y),x,FALSE),1) to force it to go through the origin, you get the original estimate 0.147233112

Comment: Oh dear I am starting to get a bit obsessed with this. The most obvious thing seems to be that you can get a better fit by using 21-y=b*exp(ax) rather than just 21-y=exp(ax). Does b definitely have to=1 in your model?

Comment: And whether the 21 is set in stone come to that?

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, I think `21` is set in stone. Roads always start at a condition of `20`(perfect) and go down to `0`(failed). `1` has been added to the range (`20` is now `21`, etc) for ease of handling. I don't think it would make any sense to have a road start at anything other than `21`.

Comment: OK. What I am basically saying is that changing .147 to .149 is just a small tweak but other things might have a bigger effect.

Comment: As for `b` needing to be `1`, unfortunately, I don't think I understand the problem well enough to answer that. I wish I did.

Comment: Perhaps back to the maths fraternity for that one. I will just post a short answer to your original question but I don't think it will get you any further forward.

Comment: I underestimated the [SO] community, it seems. Nice one @TomSharpe !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can verify that your formula for *a* translates as follows into Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E2:E22,F2:F22)/SUMSQ(E2:E22)
```

where my E2:E22 is just your x and my F2:F22 is ln(21-y). It gives the same answer, 0.147233112, as doing an exponential fit and forcing the intercept to be zero (which corresponds to setting b=1 in

```
y-21=b*exp(ax)
```

as you can verify by taking logs).

The formula quoted is the same as the one mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) under **Simple linear regression without the intercept term (single regressor)**

So this begs the question of whether b should, in fact, be equal to 1 and this is outside the scope of the question.